# how to retrive images in .xml file

Tags: php, xml

when i upload the images,it store filename in db and move images in (gallary) folders.Now i want to retrive that stored images, in xml file (demo.xml) through php code .So my ques is How to add php code in XML files or Is there any other way i can do this.here is my demo.xml file code.

```
<Piecemaker>
     <Image Source="images/las.png" Title="slide1">
Text>&lt;h1&gt;Images&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;p&gt;description area.&lt;/p&gt;</Text>
</Image>
    <Image Source="images/la.png" Title="Slide 2">
      <Text>&lt;h1&gt;Images&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;p&gt;description area.&lt;/p&gt;</Text>

    </Image>
 <Transitions>
    <Transition Pieces="9" Time="1.2" Transition="easeInOutBack" Delay="0.1" DepthOffset="300" CubeDistance="30"></Transition>
    <Transition Pieces="15" Time="3" Transition="easeInOutElastic" Delay="0.03" DepthOffset="200" CubeDistance="10"></Transition>    
  </Transitions>
</Piecemaker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Load them into a DOM, create an Xpath object for it and use expression to extract data:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$images = array();
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/Piecemaker/Image') as $node) {
  $images[] = [
    'src' => $node->getAttribute('Source'),
    'title' => $node->getAttribute('Title'),
    'description' => $xpath->evaluate('string(./Text)', $node)
  ];
}

var_dump($images);
```

Example: https://eval.in/97492

DomXpath::evaluate() can return node lists that you can traverse using `foreach` or if you use xpath functions like `string()` and `count()` a scalar value.